# Having problemns using threads to copy emails to folder in javamail

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-mail

I´m having problem to copy some emails to other folder using threads, my problem is, the code don´t wait to finish the job.

I want to move the messages by threads to accelaret the job, but I need to wait to move all messages, so how can I do this?

```
private static void moveMessagesToFolders(List<Message> listMessages, Store store, Set<String> setSender) throws MessagingException {

    HashMap<String, List<Message>> mapMessages = separeteMessagesBySender(listMessages, setSender);

    for (Entry<String, List<Message>> mapMessage : mapMessages.entrySet()) {
        Message[] messageArray = mapMessage.getValue().toArray(new Message[mapMessage.getValue().size()]);
        moveMessagesThread(messageArray, mapMessage, store);
    }
}

private static void moveMessagesThread(Message[] messageArray, Entry<String, List<Message>> mapMessage, Store store) {
    Set<Thread> setThread = createMovimentSetThread(messageArray, mapMessage, store);

    for (Thread thread : setThread) {
        thread.start();
    }
}

private static Set<Thread> createMovimentSetThread(Message[] messageArray, Entry<String, List<Message>> mapMessage, Store store) {

    int [] threadIndexs = MathUtil.generateIndex(messageArray);
    Set<Thread> setThread = new HashSet<>(threadIndexs.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < threadIndexs.length; i++) {
        setThread.add(new ThreadMoveMessages(messageArray, mapMessage, store, threadIndexs[i]));
    }

    return setThread;
}
```

After i change the method to this implementing Executor.

```
private static void moveMessagesThread(Message[] messageArray, Entry<String, List<Message>> mapMessage, Store store) {

        int [] threadIndexs = MathUtil.generateIndex(messageArray);
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            executor.execute(new ThreadMoveMessages(messageArray, mapMessage, store, threadIndexs[i]));
        }

        executor.shutdown();
    }
```

Implementing the class Thread

```
public class ThreadMoveMessages implements Callable<Boolean> {

    private Entry<String, List<Message>> mapMessage;
    private Store store;
    private Message[] messageArray;
    private static int indexControler;
    private static int indexLimit;

    public ThreadMoveMessages(Message[] messageArray, Entry<String, List<Message>> mapMessage, Store store, int indexEnd) {
        this.messageArray = Arrays.copyOf(messageArray, indexEnd);
        this.indexControler += indexEnd;
        this.indexLimit = indexControler;
        this.mapMessage = mapMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        Folder folder = null;
        try {
            folder = this.store.getDefaultFolder().getFolder(this.mapMessage.getKey());
            folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            folder.appendMessages(this.messageArray);
            EmailUtil.deleteListMessage(this.mapMessage.getValue());
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                       
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using an [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) instead of managing the thread pool directly.

Comment: @SzymonBiliński I´m reading about `Executor`, i felt confused because what I need to do?

I found people implementing new class or using a single method

Comment: You should probably start with the [basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html), than read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269445/executorservice-how-to-wait-for-all-tasks-to-finish) (waiting for all tasks to finish).

Comment: @SzymonBiliński I found one article and put changed the method, I´ve updated the question, but still have problens, I seens to don´t call the run method in thread class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Futures` and `Callables` if you want to wait compute something in asynchronous and wait for the results.

Implement `Callable` interface:

```
class MoveMessages implements Callable<Boolean> {

@Override
public Boolean call() throws Exception {
    boolean success = true;

    // Your implementation here

    return success;
}
```

}

And next submit it to Executor and retrieve `Future`, invoking `get()` on Future you will wait until computation of Callable is done.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

MoveMessages moveMessages = new MoveMessages();
Future<Boolean> submit = executor.submit(moveMessages);

Boolean integer = submit.get(); // Will wait until task is finished

executor.shutdown();
```

Of course you can submit more task gets all to list and wait until all will finish.

**Edit:**

OK, first you say that you need to wait until all messages are moved, so one way for that case is to use `Future` and `callable` with `ExecutorService`. Using `ExecutorService` you do not need to create and start lots of new threads. Remember creating new thread generate costs. In your code you create 4 new threads for each sender, using `ExecutorService` you create only fixed number of threads and reuse them for each Sender. Here is your example using `Executors` and `Futures`, note that ExecutorService is created once for invoking `moveMessagesToFolders`:

```
private static ExecutorService executor 


private static void moveMessagesToFolders(List<Message> listMessages, Store store, Set<String> setSender) throws MessagingException {
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

    HashMap<String, List<Message>> mapMessages = separeteMessagesBySender(listMessages, setSender);

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Message>> mapMessage : mapMessages.entrySet()) {
        Message[] messageArray = mapMessage.getValue().toArray(new Message[mapMessage.getValue().size()]);
        moveMessagesThread(messageArray, mapMessage, store);
    }

    executor.shutdown();
}

private static void moveMessagesThread(Message[] messageArray, Map.Entry<String, List<Message>> mapMessage, Store store) {
    List<Future<Boolean>> futures = createMovimentSetThread(messageArray, mapMessage, store);

    for (Future<Boolean> future : futures) {
        try {
            Boolean success = future.get(); // Will wait to accomplished all submited Callables
            if(!success) { // Check if all submited callables end succesulfy 
                throw new RuntimeException("Something goes wrong while moving messages");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

private static List<Future<Boolean>> createMovimentSetThread(Message[] messageArray, Map.Entry<String, List<Message>> mapMessage, Store store) {
    int [] threadIndexs = MathUtil.generateIndex(messageArray);
    List<Future<Boolean>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < threadIndexs.length; i++) {
        Future<Boolean> submit = executor.submit(new ThreadMoveMessages(messageArray, mapMessage, store, threadIndexs[i]));
        futures.add(submit);
    }

    return futures;
}
```

According to your comments, that you split array to smaller pieces using Fork/Join framework may be a better solution. Look in google for some more information. Some links:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html
- [Java 7: Fork/Join Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524634/java-7-fork-join-framework)

Comment: Ok, but I don´t need to create 5 `instances` of the `moveMessages` class?

I put the code in the question

Because i share one array in other arrays smallers to make easier the job

Comment: You can use only one thread or more to accomplished all tasks. 5 it was only for example. Read about `Executors` you will find that you can maintain only one `ExecutorSerive` for entire application so you will only submit callables to it for different invocation of `moveMessagesToFolders`. Look on this site [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#threadpools)

Comment: for you understand, I have a hahsmap with the email senders and a list of messages, i get this list and move the messages to the folders, but I want to increase the process of move message because it´s slow

Comment: I update my answer, please check if it resolving your problem. I also post 2 links to Fork/Join Framework maybe it will be a better solution for you (Dividing array to smaller pieces).

Comment: I´ve got doing it by using thread, but the time is higher than without thread

Comment: So the biggest problem in application are I/O operations. You have asked for solution to wait until all threads are finished, and you post code sample for that problem. Reading `ThreadMoveMessages` I can only suggest to move messages instead of coping it, it will be much faster. I think you should create new question about that problem.

Comment: Yes I thought i/o woudn´t have problem, but have, but your code help me in other ways, because I need to make other things with threads in my code